# There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null" with database authentication

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I successfully build in-memory authentication. But when I going to build it with database comes this error.

> There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"

This is followed tutorial - [Spring Boot Tutorial for Beginners, 10 - Advanced Authentication using Spring Security | Mighty Java](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6v-LnpUQSs)

There are classes

### SpringSecurityConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfiguration extends 
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Autowired
private AuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint;

@Autowired
private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint);
}

}
```

### AuthenticationEntryPoint.java

```
@Configuration
public class AuthenticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint{


@Override
public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {

    response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm -" +getRealmName());
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.println("Http Status 401 "+authException.getMessage());
}

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    setRealmName("MightyJava");
    super.afterPropertiesSet();
}
```

}

### MyUserDetailsService .java

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if(user == null){
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User Name "+username +"Not Found");
    }
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUserName(),user.getPassword(),getGrantedAuthorities(user));
}

private Collection<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(User user){

    Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthority = new ArrayList<>();
    if(user.getRole().getName().equals("admin")){
        grantedAuthority.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
    }
    grantedAuthority.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    return grantedAuthority;
}
}
```

### UserRepository interface

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{

@Query("FROM User WHERE userName =:username")
User findByUsername(@Param("username") String username);

}
```

### Role.java

```
@Entity
public class Role extends AbstractPersistable<Long>{

private String name;

@OneToMany(targetEntity = User.class , mappedBy = "role" , fetch = FetchType.LAZY ,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<User> users;

//getter and setter
}
```

### User.java

```
@Entity
public class User extends AbstractPersistable<Long>{

//AbstractPersistable class ignore primary key and column annotation(@Column)

private String userId;
private String userName;
private String password;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
private Role role;

@OneToMany(targetEntity = Address.class, mappedBy = "user",fetch= FetchType.LAZY ,cascade =CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Address> address; //Instead of Set(Unordered collection and not allow duplicates) we can use list(ordered and allow duplicate values) as well

//getter and setter}
```

If you have any idea plese inform. Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I changed MyUserDetailsService class adding `passwordEncoder` method.

Added lines

```
BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = passwordEncoder();
```

Changed Line

```
//changed, user.getPassword() as encoder.encode(user.getPassword())
return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(--)
```

### MyUserDetailsService.java

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = passwordEncoder();
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if(user == null){
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User Name "+username +"Not Found");
    }
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUserName(),encoder.encode(user.getPassword()),getGrantedAuthorities(user));
}

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

As from Spring Security 5.x, Spring Security enforces you to use a password encoder if you're working with other than in-memory (production) databases.

Spring Security enforces this by activating the default `DelegatingPasswordEncoder`, which looks for `PasswordEncoder` beans.
By adding a `BCryptPasswordEncoder`, the `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` will return that instance to encrypt passwords.

```
@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

> I don't recommend you to do this, but if you really want to, you can override password encoding by adding `{noop}` to the password value.
>   This will treat the password by activating the `NoOpPasswordEncoder` instead of the default `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` and will treat your password as plain text.
>   Please note that this is not recommended if you deploy your app to a production environment!