# There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null" in spring basic security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

my code is working fine in spring version 1.5.6.RELEASE.
But when i upgrade version to 2.0.0, some of my methods have been deprecated but works fine.
when i change my deprecated method by looking from [There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null" with database authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49617349/there-is-no-passwordencoder-mapped-for-the-id-null-with-database-authenticatio)
it starts giving me the error "there is no passwordencoder"

Here is my code.

**WebConfig**

```
@Configurable
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
AppUserDetailsService appUserDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(appUserDetailsService);
}

@Bean
public static DelegatingPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
 return (DelegatingPasswordEncoder) DelegatingPasswordEncoder.encode("noop");
}

protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(appUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");

        }
    };
}
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    super.configure(web);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/account/register","/account/login","/logout").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and()
    .logout()
    .permitAll()
    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", "POST"))
    .and()
    .httpBasic().and()
.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED).and()
    .csrf().disable();
}

}
```

**Account Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("account")
public class AccountController {

public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccountController.class);

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> createUser(@RequestBody User newUser) {
    if (userService.find(newUser.getUsername()) != null) {
        logger.error("username Already exist " + newUser.getUsername());
        return new ResponseEntity(
                new CustomErrorType("user with username " + newUser.getUsername() + "already exist "),
                HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
    newUser.setRole("USER");

    return new ResponseEntity<User>(userService.save(newUser), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/login")
public Principal user(Principal principal) {
    logger.info("user logged "+principal);
    return principal;
}
}
```

**User Service**

```
@Service
public class UserService {

@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

public User save(User user) {
    return userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
}

public User update(User user) {
    return userRepository.save(user);
}

public User find(String userName) {
    return userRepository.findOneByUsername(userName);
}
}
```

I see all the related answers but they are available for inMemory authentication.
[Spring security : migrating 4.0 to 5.0 - Error -There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id “null”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49609768/spring-security-migrating-4-0-to-5-0-error-there-is-no-passwordencoder-mapp)
[Spring Security 5 : There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49654143/spring-security-5-there-is-no-passwordencoder-mapped-for-the-id-null)
[Spring Boot PasswordEncoder Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999940/spring-boot-passwordencoder-error?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Please help.
I'm using mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation :

> NoOpPasswordEncoder : A password encoder that does nothing. Useful
>   for testing where working with plain text passwords may be preferred.

They were deprecated because they aren't secured. As i see, if you still want to use "noop" password encoder, just build your own password encoder implementation.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/NoOpPasswordEncoder.java

Hope this helps.